# Generic type (T) with type argument (TT) to have a property of that type argument type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

*Sorry for a bit embarrassing question title, but I could not figure out how to describe the situation more clearly.*

Let's say, I have four classes:

```
public class CustomModel
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomModel2 : CustomModel
{

}

public class CustomViewModel<T> where T : CustomModel
{

}

public class PageOfType<T, TT> where T : CustomViewModel<TT> where TT : CustomModel
{
    public TT Model { get; set; }  
    public T ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

So, the idea is pretty simple: I want `PageOfType` to have some property of a type, which `is an argument of type` which `is an argument for itself`.

So, the instantiation looks like this (which is a bit complicated and would not be so nicely used in development process):

```
var p0 = new PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>, CustomModel>();
var p1 = new PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>, CustomModel2>();
// ^^ this line gives an error as, obviously, CustomViewModel<CustomModel> and CustomViewModel<CustomModel2> are not convertable

p0.Model.Value1 = "some string"; // <- this line is perfectly what I need (it works)
```

So, could you give me any clue on:

- **how should I arrange all that "kitchen" for simply** having something like this instead (in other words, **not to mention `CustomModel` twice** on initialization):

  ```
  var p0 = new PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>>();
  // or even having new PageOfType<CustomViewModel2>(); 
  // (if CustomViewModel2 is just as:
  // public class CustomViewModel2 : CustomViewModel<CustomModel>
  // for instance)
  ```
- how can I handle the convertable error with this (as I am not sure I am able to use interfaces in this situation easily (unless I don't have another choice)):

  ```
  var p1 = new PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>, CustomModel2>();
  // ^^ this line gives an error as...
  ```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks, John.

Comment: If you can assign an initial ViewModel. Consider using a factory method for initiating a new instance of PageOfType since methods support type inference. This allows a construct like: `PageOfType.Create(customViewModel);`

Comment: Are you always going to instantiate `PageOfType<T,TT>` with specifically `CustomViewModel` as `T`?

Comment: Rather, yes. I would need that just to have something like that for the page definition: `@inherits PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModle>>` (with ability to use `this.Model.Value1`). (Again, this is not about MVC, but C#).

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use a covariant interface instead of a class: `ICustomViewModel<out TModel>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, even if I've already mentioned "**as I am not sure I am able to use interfaces in this situation easily**" (due to my code logic) (but if have no other choice), that solves the second issue (to allow the code to compile). But the main question is still about such complicated initialization `PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>, CustomModel>();` to simplify, because if it leaves as it is, not sure the development process will be pretty convenient (and simple).

Comment: I am affreaid there is no better way to do that. You havd to use a covariant interface. I am not sure about the second part of your question

Comment: As for the second part you gotta use a definiyion like this: `class CustomPage<TModel> : PageOfType<ICustomViewModel<TModel>>`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am not looking for the way to define that, but rather easily instantiate (instead of duplication in here: `new PageOfType<CustomViewModel<CustomModel>, CustomModel>()`). Because my final PageOfType obviously must have both: CustomViewModel and also CustomModel types for corresponding properties.